# Using plotly express px.bar causes a shift in output

Tags: python, time-series, plotly, bar-chart, plotly-express

I am trying to print a bar chart using plotly express (px.bar).  It is a yearly set of data from 2015 to 2022 but gets plotted from 2016 to 2023.  Not sure why...

Code to plot yearly returns.

```
# plotting the yearly % returns
fig = px.bar(yearly, x='Date', y=['Model','Benchmark'], title="Yearly Profit", labels={'value':
     'Percent', 'variable':''},barmode = 'group')
new = {'Model':'Model %', 'Benchmark': bMark + ' %'}   # Change the column names for the legend
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = new[t.name]))
fig.show()
```

Here is the input “yearly.”

|  | Date | Model | Benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2015-12-31 00:00:00 | 72.7922 | 1.23411 |
| 1 | 2016-12-30 00:00:00 | 27.1839 | 11.9969 |
| 2 | 2017-12-29 00:00:00 | 39.9856 | 21.7039 |
| 3 | 2018-12-31 00:00:00 | 15.6401 | -4.56891 |
| 4 | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 | 42.3679 | 31.2216 |
| 5 | 2020-12-31 00:00:00 | 211.67 | 18.3307 |
| 6 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | 56.0862 | 28.7285 |
| 7 | 2022-10-31 00:00:00 | -1.97482 | -17.7437 |

Here is the output chart.

[image]

Comment: Add the input file as a text not an image. see df.to_dict() and/or df.to_markdown() to do so

Comment: I believe it is text now.  Thanks for the help.  First post so I'm sorry for any inconveniences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not exactly the answer you're looking for, but a workaround is shown below :

Explicitly get a "Year" column:

```
yearly['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(yearly['Date'])
yearly['Year'] = yearly['Date'].dt.year
```

Use that in your figure:

```
fig = px.bar(yearly, x='Year', y=['Model','Benchmark'], title="Yearly Profit", labels={'value':
     'Percent', 'variable':''},barmode = 'group')
new = {'Model':'Model %', 'Benchmark': 'bMark' + ' %'}   # Change the column names for the legend
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(name = new[t.name]))
fig.show()
```

This shows the years as per expectation.

Comment: Bingo, that worked. I just put .year on the end. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Date` column is of the `datetime` data type (if not, first do this: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`), here's what you can do:

Extract the year attribute to a new column:

```
df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year.astype(int)
```

Finally, you can specify the range of the year you want in plotly:

```
fig = px.bar(yearly, x='year', y=['Model','Benchmark'], title="Yearly Profit", labels={'value':
     'Percent', 'variable':''},barmode = 'group', range_x = [2015, 2022])
```

By directly extracting the year from the Date column, you are able to circumvent the issue you are encountering.